# Understanding Assembly language output of a C program

Tags: assembly

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 static int i = 100;

 /* Declard as extern since defined in hello.c */
 extern int global;

 int function(char *input)
 {
  printf("%s\n", input);
  return global;
 }; 

    .file   "foo.c"
    .data
    .align 4
    .type   i, @object
    .size   i, 4
i:
    .long   100
    .text
.globl function
    .type   function, @function
function:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    puts
    movl    global, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .size   function, .-function
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

What is the reason for the:

> subl $24, %esp

Why is he making space on the stack for local variables by decrementing the stackpointer by 24 bytes? There are no local variables in the function.
Then he does:

> movl %eax, (%esp)

Why - Because the value(pointer char *input) stored at ebp+8 was moved to eax 
and should now be passed to puts.. but then why does he do the prior subl -
To store the return value of int? But that's 4 bytes..Also i read that C did 
not support the calling function having to make space on the stack for the 
return value (renetrancy issues). What is going on here please :( ?? He could 
be aligning the pointer argument on a word boundary.. but then the SysV I386 
ABI says that tail padding is employed..

Also,

> movl %esp, %ebp

implies that esp and ebp will both point to the base of the new functions stack 
frame. But, assuming there was a 'call function;' consider the stack:
You'd have:

> ```
> pushl ptr //push char *ptr
> call function 
> {
> pushl ebp So stack contains:
> ptr
> ret-value
> ebp
> ->with-esp-pointing-to-after-ebp
> (ESP always points to the top of the stack but after the last pushed   
> element..?)
> ```

So he's setting ebp to esp. But in the ABI specification on pg36, SysV ABI 
I386 Architecture Processor Supplement 4E, he says:
    0(%ebp) previous %ebp (optional)
I'm guessing that reads: %ebp+0 points to previous ebp
But as you can see, ebp+0 actually points to after the stored previous ebp..???

also in another program,

> ```
> andl $-16, %esp
> subl $32, %esp
> ```

so he's first nueking the last 4 bits of esp.. umm how much space does that 
give him? and then the subl..

Could someone suggest a decent tutorial or book for this.. I don't want to 
master assembly, just want to know enough to understand a bit of the ABI specification and alignment and GOT/PLT/Virtual-addressing and compiler/linker
stuff-symbolTable/relocation etc (i'm using the Levine book but it's huge - interesting though but COFF and IBM/Sparc stuff :( which is why I started with 
the ABI spec. There's also Ian Wienand's web site: Computer Science from the 
Bottom Up.)

Comment: What optimizations were enabled when you compiled this function?

Comment: none.. just did gcc -S whatever http://www.bottomupcs.com/compilation_example.html

Comment: These weird things come from your CPU architecture, so all things from this code you should find in your book.

Comment: If you compile without optimization, then don't be surprised that the output is not optimized.